# open() throwing mypy issues which reading an image file

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I have the following line of code which reads an image (which is fed into a `POST` request):

```
files = {"image": (image_path, open(image_path, "rb"))}
```

While trying to run this through `mypy`, it keeps throwing the following error:

```
Argument 1 to "open" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "Union[Union[str, bytes, PathLike[str], PathLike[bytes]], int]"
```

I've tried searching this, but I've not found a solution for similar problems.

Is there a different way to read filepaths in order to avoid these issues?

Comment: If you add an `assert image_path is not None` before this statement mypy should be satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Not the correct answer but if you want to temporarily make it go away to move ahead:

```
# type: ignore
```

at the end of the erroring line should work.